# How to display AlertDialog with ImageView and EditText without layout.xml?

Tags: java, android

I have created an alert dialog with an image. However, I need to display the image together with the EditText programatically.

Here's the code..

```
    final EditText input = new EditText(getActivity());

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(((EwiseDemoApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getApplicationContext());
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bitmapDecodedString, 0, bitmapDecodedString.length);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    input.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());

    AAlertDialog alertDialog =  new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
            .setView(imageView)
            .setPositiveButton("Submit",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            //some method here
                        }
                    }
            )
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            dialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }
            )
            .create(); 
    //other codes here
```

Comment: What do you have against xml?

Comment: then you would have to programmatically create that layout and set it with `setView()`

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code:

```
private void displayDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alert.setTitle("Your Title");

    EditText editText = new EditText(this);
    alert.setView(editText);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    alert.setView(imageView);

    alert.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
           //Do stuff
        }
    });

    alert.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            //Do stuff
        }
    });
    alert.show();
}
```

Comment: You can't call `alert.setView` with two views and expect both to be displayed

Answer (score -1):

you need to create a layout and set it to the view of your alertDialog.Or you could use DialogFragment.